# Core Data: Return only one result per name

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a Core Data database containing multiple items with the same value for a name property. These are representing different versions of the same thing. I would like to be able to perform searches on the database using predicates, but have the option to have it return no more than one row with the same name.

I could filter out duplicates after performing the search, but there could be a lot of them, so it would definitely be better to get the database to just cut out the duplicates for me.

Context:

I'm trying to recreate some functionality of a site called Scryfall in a local database. This database searches different printings of Magic the Gathering cards. Here's an example:
[On Scryfall I can search for Magic cards where the card's type is "praetor".](https://scryfall.com/search?q=t%3Apraetor) It will show me all the cards that match my query, but only one version of each card.
[I can also do a search where I add "unique:prints" to my query.](https://scryfall.com/search?q=t%3Apraetor+unique%3Aprints) Now it will show me the same cards, but include every unique print, including reprints across multiple expansions, or things like alternate art or promo cards. Each print's name should be the same if it represents the same card.

My database has a row for every print and I let the user search for cards. I'd like to give the user the same option that Scryfall has where you can choose to show unique prints, but hide all but one print of each card by default. Right now it just always shows every print.

Any way to do this? I’m still learning Core Data.

Thanks!!

EDIT:

If I process the results from my fetch request like this after I perform it, I get the results I want. I'm looking for a way to modify the fetch request itself so that this step isn't necessary.

```
let request: NSFetchRequest = ...
var results = try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(request)
            
if !uniquePrints {
    results = results.reduce([], { partialResult, card in
        var partial = partialResult
        if !partial.contains(where: { $0.name == card.name }) {
            partial.append(card)
        }
        return partial
    })
}
            
return results
```

Comment: Which one would you want to show? Each different print of a card is an entity? They aren't regrouped? A possible way, would be to have a boolean with "isMainPrint" value, which would be the "unique" card (like "English print if possible & last printed one), value that could change over time (if a card is reedited, like "lands" as the most basic one). And you could check that value in your query.

Comment: Do you need show a single result even if the predicate/ filter set on the fetchRequest is returning say x results ?
Not sure if I could exactly understand the scenario but you can check NSFetchRequest setLimit property and set it to 1.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It depends on how you want to choose the one to show. If there are 10, but you want to show only 1, which one is the right one? You need to know the answer to that question before you can write code to handle it. If it doesn't matter, and you can just choose any of them, try setting `fetchLimit` to 1 on the fetch.

Comment: @TomHarrington I can’t just set fetchLimit to 1, unfortunately. For example… each card has colors associated with it. If a user wants to search for all blue cards, I want to give them the option to either see one print of each card that’s blue or every print of each card that’s blue. The latter is what I’m currently getting.

Comment: @CompC It’s very hard to understand the problem you’re trying to solve. You can probably do it in Core Data but right now it seems like you need an expert in this game (or whatever it is) to understand your question. If you can explain the problem in terms that don’t rely on already knowing how Scryfall works, someone may be able to help.

Comment: I feel like I'm just doing a bad job explaining the problem, because the problem itself doesn't have to do with the game.

Comment: @TomHarrington I added some code to my problem that might help explain it better?

Comment: From your code it looks like you need a `predicate` for your fetch request to fetch only results with a particular `name`.